# jqGrid additional POST data editURL with inline editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

need help on sending addtional editURL data to the server. below is my code but it is not working

```
progGrid.jqGrid({
    url         : rootURLProgExecList,
    editurl     : '/ProgGrid.php',
    editData    : {'action':'weekID','userID':userID},
    mtype       : "POST",
    postData    : {'action':'weekID','userID':userID},
    datatype    : "JSON",
    page        : 1,
    regional    : lang,
    colNames    : progWeekColName[lang],
    colModel    : [
                    { name: 'userID', width: 25, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'weekID', key: true, editable: true, width: 20, editrules : { required: true, integer:true, minValue:1} },
                  ],
    loadonce    : true,
    autowidth   : true,
    height      : 445,
    rowNum      : 20,
    caption     : progGridCaption,
    subGrid     : true, // set the subGrid property to true to show expand buttons for each row
    subGridRowExpanded  : showChildGrid, // javascript function that will take care of showing the child grid
    subGridOptions      : {
            expandOnLoad: false, // expand all rows on load
            plusicon    : "fa fa-plus-circle",
            minusicon   : "fa fa-minus-circle"
    },
    subGridBeforeExpand: function(divid, rowid) {
    var expanded = jQuery("td.sgexpanded", "#progGrid")[0];
        if(expanded) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(expanded).trigger("click");
            }, 100);
        }
    },
    shrinkToFit : true,
    sortorder   : "asc",
    hidegrid    : false,
    gridview    : true,
    pgbuttons   : false,     // disable page control like next, back button
    pgtext      : null,
    viewrecords : true,
    recordtext  : '{0}-{1} / {2}',
    pager       : progGridPager
})
.navGrid(progGridPager, {edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, view: false, search:false})
.inlineNav(progGridPager,{edit: true, add: true, del: true, cancel: true, refresh : true,
            editParams: {keys: true},
            addParams : {keys: true}});

    // the event handler on expanding parent row receives two parameters
    // the ID of the grid tow  and the primary key of the row  subgrid_id
function showChildGrid(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
    var childGridID = parentRowID + "_day";
    var childGridPagerID = parentRowKey + "_pager";
    // send the parent row primary key to the server so that we know which grid to show
    // add a table and pager HTML elements to the parent grid row - we will render the child grid here
    $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID + ' class=scroll></div>');

    $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
        url         : rootURLProgExecList,
        editurl     : '/ProgGrid.php',
        editData    : {'action':'day', 'userID':userID,'weekID' : parentRowKey},
        mtype       : "POST",
        postData    : {'action':'day','userID':userID,'weekID' : parentRowKey},
        datatype    : "json",
        page        : 1,
        regional    : lang,
        caption     : progWeekCaption[lang],
        colNames    : progDayColName[lang],
        colModel    : [
                        { name: 'week_ID',  width: 75, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'dayID', key: true, width: 100, editable:true, editrules : { required: true, integer:true, minValue:1, maxValue:7}, },
                      ],
        loadonce    : true,
        autowidth   : true,
        //width     : 500,
        height      : '100%',
        subGrid     : true, // set the subGrid property to true to show expand buttons for each row
        subGridRowExpanded: showThirdLevelChildGrid, // javascript function that will take care of showing the child grid
        subGridOptions      : {
                expandOnLoad: false, // expand all rows on load
                plusicon: "fa fa-plus-circle",
                minusicon: "fa fa-minus-circle"
        },
        subGridBeforeExpand: function(divid, rowid) {
        // #grid is the id of the grid
        var expanded = jQuery("td.sgexpanded", "#" + childGridID )[0];
            if(expanded) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(expanded).trigger("click");
                }, 100);
            }
        },
        shrinkToFit : true,
        sortorder   : "asc",
        hidegrid    : true,
        gridview    : true,
        pgbuttons   : false,     // disable page control like next, back button
        pgtext      : null,
        viewrecords : true,
        recordtext  : '{0}-{1}/{2}',
        pager: '#' + childGridPagerID
    })
    .navGrid('#' + childGridPagerID, {edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, view: false, search:false})
    .inlineNav('#' + childGridPagerID,{edit: true, add: true, del: true, cancel: true, refresh : true, editParams: {keys: true,}, addParams: {keys: true}});
}
```

I tried adding the additional data to the addParams and editParams like this 
addParams: {keys: true,{'action':'weekID','userID':userID}}
editParams: {keys: true,{'action':'weekID','userID':userID}} with no luck.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `addParams` option should looks like

```
addParams: {addRowParams: {keys: true}}
```

instead of

```
addParams : {keys: true}
```

To add more custom data posted to the server during inline editing, like `{'action':'weekID','userID':userID}`, you can use to `extraparam`:

```
.navGrid(progGridPager, {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false})
.inlineNav(progGridPager, {
    editParams: {keys: true, extraparam: {action:'weekID', userID:userID}},
    addParams: {addRowParams:{keys:true,extraparam:{action:'weekID',userID:userID}}}});
```

I see you use [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I develop alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (the current version is 4.12.0). It supports simplified form of providing the options, described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). If you would use the options you can reduce your code and simplify it.

I would strictly recommend you additionally to use `idPrefix` option at least for subgrids. For example you can use `idPrefix: "s_" + parentRowKey + "_"`. It's very important to prevent id duplicates.

Comment: thank you Oleg, it works great. I will consider switching to the free jqGrid but right now i'm pressed on time and don't want to go to the process of changing all the jqgrid codes. also notices not a lot of documentation for the free jqgrid from the wiki you provided, not sure if they are located somewhere else.

Comment: @boulepick: You are welcome! I described in the wiki and in readmes to every version mostly **the new features** implemented in free jqGrid, but I try to hold maximal compatibility with old versions of jqGrid. Moreover I publish free jqGrid in different repositories and on two CDNs (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). Using CDNs is really recommended way to use jqGrid and it allows to test free jqGrid by just changing URLs to jqGrid files which you use.